# Objective-C NSURLConnection with RESTful web service, error handling

Tags: objective-c, ios, restful-authentication

I´m connection to a RESTful web service, using JSON to retrive data. The problem i have is that the server gives a 200 OK response even if the username and password is wrong. It then responds with a html page with instructions. 
I want to do some error handling when a user is logging in, is there a way in Objective-C to check the content-type of the response and compare that to "application/json"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSURLResponse` class has a `MIMEType` property which I think can be used.

Or, for HTTP, there is the `allHeaderFields` on `NSHTTPURLResponse` which returns a dictionary of the response headers (then you just check the `Content-Type` header).

Comment: Ok, I will give that a shot. Thanks a lot for the quick answer.